# Is there a way to find out whether ffmpeg is performing optimally in my system using a ffmpeg command of sorts?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm encoding a file (mediainfo below) using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i AHomeMovie.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 17 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -threads 8 resultdir/AHomeMovie.mkv
```

And getting more or less the following performance after a couple of minutes:

```
frame= 2036 fps=2.5 q=22.0 size=   87535kB time=00:01:25.25 bitrate=8411.2kbits/s speed=0.104x
```

Is this normal performance for a laptop with a i7-8550U, 16gb of RAM, UHD graphics 620 running Linux? Is there a way to find out whether ffmpeg is performing optimally using a ffmpeg command of sorts? I know it's commodity hardware by now but I just want to get some perspective on how the system is performing. I'm aware that I can use a different -preset speed btw.

Mediainfo:

```
General
Unique ID                                : 25145236523685421256398752247554522365 (0x14258745965823652446224452555874)
Complete name                            : AHomeMovie.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 6.35 GiB
Duration                                 : 22 min 47 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 39.9 Mb/s
Movie name                               : A Home Movie
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-09-10 22:10:12
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v42.0.0 ('Overtime') 64-bit
Writing library                          : libebml v1.3.10 + libmatroska v1.5.2

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 22 min 45 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 38.0 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 40.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.764
Stream size                              : 6.04 GiB (95%)
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : FLAC
Format/Info                              : Free Lossless Audio Codec
Codec ID                                 : A_FLAC
Duration                                 : 22 min 45 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 614 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 11.719 FPS (4096 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Stream size                              : 100 MiB (2%)
Writing library                          : libFLAC 1.2.1 (UTC 2007-09-17)
Language                                 : Japanese
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : FLAC
Format/Info                              : Free Lossless Audio Codec
Codec ID                                 : A_FLAC
Duration                                 : 22 min 46 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 317 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 11.719 FPS (4096 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Delay relative to video                  : 24 ms
Stream size                              : 215 MiB (3%)
Writing library                          : libFLAC 1.2.1 (UTC 2007-09-17)
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
```

Answer (score 2):

## It is already optimized

You are encoding with libx264. This is an encoder with excellent default settings, so there is not much optimization to do.

Only performance recommendation is to not manually declare threads and it will automatically use an optimal value for your hardware. So remove `-threads 8` and let it choose.

Basic recommendation is to use the slowest `-preset` you have patience for and the highest `-crf` value that looks acceptable. That's it. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

#### H.264 → H.264: Why re-encode in the first place?

The most optimal process would be to not re-encode. You're introducing [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

#### Hardware encoder

You may be able to use [QuickSync](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync) to encode. It may be relatively fast and spare more of your CPU for other tasks, but it will never look as good as x264 given the same bitrate.

#### x265

It's not clear why you are re-encoding, but if your input was encoded inefficiently and space is a premium, you can consider encoding with libx265 to output HEVC format. It is much slower than x264, but you may see some file size reduction.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265 / HEVC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

Comment: Why re-encode in the first place? Filesize. 6.5GB for a 23 minute video is overkill for my purpose. After reencoding both files look virtually the same (crf 17) with the reencoded file being 1/6 of the original filesize.